# Python - Ways to create dataframe with multiple sources and conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have several dataframes that contain relevant information that need to be compiled into one single dataframe. There are several conditions involved in choosing which pieces of data can be brought over to the results dataframe.

Here are 3 dataframes (columns only) that we need to pull and compile data from:

```
df1 = ["Date","Order#","Line#","ProductID","Quantity","Sale Amount"]
df2 = ["Date","PurchaseOrderID","ProductID","Quantity","Cost"]
df3 = ["ProductID","Quantity","Location","Cost"]
```

df3 is the only table in this set that actually contains a unique non-repeating key "productid". The other two dataframes have keys, but they can repeat. the only way to find uniqueness is to refer to date and the other foreign keys.
Now, we'd like the desired result to show which all products grouped by product where df1.date after x date, where df2.quantity<5, where df3.quantity>0. Ideally the results would show the df3.quantity, df.cost (sum both in grouping), most recent purchase date from df2.date, and total number of sale by part from df1.count where all above criteria met.

This is the quickest example I could come up with on this issue. I'm able to accomplish this in VBA with only one problem... **it's *EXCRUCIATINGLY* slow**. I understand how list comprehension and perhaps other means of completing this task would be faster than VBA (maybe?), but it would still take a while with all of the logic and decision making that happens behind the scenes.
This example doesn't exactly show the complexities but any advice or direction you have to offer may help me and others understand how to treat these kinds of problems in Python. Any expert opinion, advice, direction is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? If you can do it in VBA, odds are you can do it in Pandas. In any case, it can't hurt to try.

Comment: how do you think it should be approached? Habits tell me to loop but not sure how Python would fare. it's only 150k rows total, but with all of the logic involved.. it's over a second per row. perhaps I should loop through and create a list for the results for each column then zip em together? will these line up despite the varying keys? This may be a gap in my fundamental understanding of how to work within pandas. youtube hasn't been very helpful with this specific problem haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

You simply need to apply the conditions as filters on each dataframe, then group by `ProductID` and put it together.

```
df1 = df1[df1.Date > x].groupby('ProductID').agg({'Quantity':'sum','Sale Amount':'sum'})
df2 = df2.groupby('ProductID').agg({'Date':'max','Quantity':'sum','Cost':'sum'})
df2 = df2[df2.Quantity > 5].copy()
df3 = df3[df3.Quantity > 0].copy()
```

Once you have all of those, probably something like:

```
g = [i for i in list(df3.index) if i in list(df2.index) and i in list(df1.index)]
df = df3.loc[g] #use df3 as a frame, with only needed indexes
```

I am not sure what you want to pull from `df1` and `df2` - but it will look something like:

```
df = df.join(df2['col_needed'])
```

You may need to rename columns to avoid overlap.

This avoids inefficient looping and should be orders of magnitude faster than a loop in VBA.

Comment: This is what I was trying to figure out. This worked for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If that's the end for this question, please do accept the answer by clicking the tick underneath the upvote/downvote buttons :)

Comment: apologies, I forgot to do that initially. thank you again!